# Why does my tkinter gui not show a line and takes so long to load?

Tags: python-2.7, animation, pandas, matplotlib, tkinter

Good day

I am requesting help with the below "Python Tkinter Gui".

I would like the program to read from a text file, and output a line graph inside the Tkinter Gui.

I have watched all the relevant videos and I have attempted multiple variations before seeking advice. I would like the graph to be animated (automatically refreshes itself<0, however at this point I will be happy to at least see a stagnant line on the graph that depicts my current data and has a refresh button.

The problem is that after slowly loading, the gui appears, and then the gui freezes with no line displayed. To be clear the graph is displayed in the topframe tkinter canvas, no line is visible for the user to see the data, and the gui ends up freezing.

I have been successful with Matplotlib reading the text file as a dataframe and opens up a standard graph without Tkinter. I can also open the text file with multiple other methods correctly.

The data in the text file currently looks like the output below, and I would like the line graph to show the Date and Time on the X-Axis and the Events on the Y-Axis.

```
datetime       event
20160117161947,1
20160117161951,1
20160117162028,1
20160117162057,2
20160117162128,1
20160117162140,2
20160117162227,1
20160117162228,1
20160117162313,1
20160117162328,1
20160117162356,1
20160117162428,1
20160117162520,2
20160117162528,1
20160117162607,1
20160117162624,5
20160117162628,1
20160117162728,1
```

This is another sample of the text file. I am just using SED to strip out the special characters and spaces.

```
 datetime            event
2016-01-06 21:22:57 , 18
2016-01-06 21:23:08 , 2
2016-01-06 21:23:09 , 2
2016-01-06 21:23:10 , 1
2016-01-06 21:23:13 , 1
2016-01-06 21:23:31 , 3
2016-01-06 21:23:43 , 1
2016-01-06 21:24:05 , 3
2016-01-06 21:24:09 , 3
2016-01-06 21:24:13 , 1
2016-01-06 21:24:19 , 2
2016-01-06 21:24:21 , 2
2016-01-06 21:24:31 , 3
2016-01-06 21:24:43 , 1
2016-01-06 21:24:49 , 2
2016-01-06 21:24:50 , 17
```

Here is the tkinter code. This  code works to create a graph but does not include a line or any of my data (date, time, or events). Also, as I mentioned it takes a long time to load.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# standard numpy and pandas
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series,DataFrame

#import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
#for python 2.7 from Tkinter use ttk is below
import ttk

#import running shell scripts
import subprocess

# Run tkinter code in another thread
import threading

# import for console code
import os

# standard graph imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series,DataFrame
import matplotlib
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#special imports matplotlib and tkinter related

matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg,  

NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

#livedata import
import time
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style

#graph style
LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana",12)
style.use("ggplot")

f = Figure(figsize=(4,4), dpi=50)
a = f.add_subplot(111)


root = Tk()

topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack(expand=YES)

botFrame = Frame(root)
botFrame.pack(side = BOTTOM, expand=YES)


df = pd.read_table('../data/linedata/test.txt', sep=",")
df.columns = ['datetime', 'event']
xar = []
yar = []
for x in df:
   if x > 1:
      xar.append(df.datetime)
      yar.append(df.event)
a.clear()
a.plot(xar,yar)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, root)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, root)
#toolbar.update()
#canvas.tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

#left side rectangle placer
canvas = Canvas(botFrame, width = 150, height = 600)
canvas.pack(side = LEFT, expand=True)
canvas.create_rectangle(5,5,175,700, fill="white")



root.geometry("900x900")

#animation interval time and stuff
#ani = animation.FuncAnimation(f, animation, interval=1000)

root.mainloop()
```

sometimes I receive the error below and I am also curious on what it means.

```
usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib-1.5.0_918.gb6a79ac-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/__init__.py:1355: UserWarning:  This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect
because the backend has already been chosen;
matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.

  warnings.warn(_use_error_msg)
root@Ghostnetdeb:/home/jinverar/projects/honeynet/views# python basicdfline.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib-1.5.0_918.gb6a79ac-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/__init__.py:1355: UserWarning:  This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect
because the backend has already been chosen;
matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.
```

Comment: could anyone assist?

Comment: Regarding the errors, just read them it says that `matplotlib.use("TkAgg")` should be imported before `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`...

Comment: I moved the import and that did clear the error, Thank you B8vrede. 

The line graph is still not working. Could anyone assist with that?

Comment: might be threading or sockets. When the line loads in a matplotlib plot it's fine but no luck with Tkinter. I could be moving towards learning QT designer. Could anyone help out?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue with the below code used within the inside of the main Gui.  I have also created a program to write data to the text file with the push of a gui button. The graph will refresh every time I close and re-open the Gui. Can someone help me animate a live graph that always updates when the text file updates?

```
#graph STATIC WORKING****DONT"MESS

#style.use("ggplot")
plt.style.use("seaborn-deep")

df = pd.read_table('data/newdata/linedata.txt', sep=",")
df.columns = ['datetime', 'event']

plt = Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=40)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0.06, top = 0.98, left = 0.04, right = 0.97)
ax = plt.add_subplot(111)

ax.clear()
df.plot(kind='line', x='datetime', y='event', ax=ax)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(plt, root)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, root)
```